# Вынести в класс операции с двоичными числами

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Выполняю лабораторные работы по программированию, на языке C#.

Задание заключается в усложнении проекта из предыдущей лабораторной работы. Теперь задание нужно реализовать в
отдельном классе. Объекты класса создаются, и вызов методов осуществляется в основном классе в методе Main(). По возможности реализовать перегрузку математический операций.

В 6 лабе было такое задание: Составить программу для представления строки, позволяющей хранить только двоичное число и выполнять с ним арифметические операции. Предусмотреть инициализацию с проверкой допустимости значений.
Программу я составил, теперь помогите пожалуйста усложнить её.

Код программы:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace ConsoleApp44 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            String buf;
 
            String s1, s2;
            Console.WriteLine("Программа для работы с классом двоичного числа");
            Console.WriteLine("Введдите 1-е двоичное число");
            s1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите 2-е двоичное число");
            s2 = Console.ReadLine();
            binary bin1 = new binary(s1);
            binary bin2 = new binary();
            bin2.Binary = s2;
 
            Console.WriteLine(bin1.sum(s2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class binary {
        private String sBinary;
        public binary() {
            sBinary = "0";
        }
        public binary(string Binary) {
            if (sBIN(Binary)) {
                this.sBinary = Binary;
            }
            else { sBinary = "0"; }
        }
        public bool sBIN(string str) {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++) {
                if (str[i] != '1' && str[i] != '0')
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public string Binary {
            get {
                return this.sBinary;
            }
            set {
                this.sBinary = value;
            }
        }
        private long GetDes(string str) {
            long buf = (str[0] - '0');
            for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++) {
                buf *= 2;
                buf += (str[i] - '0');
            }
            return buf;
        }
        public String GetBin(long dec) {
            long buf = dec;
            String bstr = "";
            while (buf != 0) {
                bstr += buf % 2;
                buf /= 2;
            }
            string rstr = "";
 
            for (int i = (bstr.Length - 1); i > 0; i--) {
                rstr += bstr[i];
            }
            return rstr;
        }
        public string sum(string str) {
            long b1, b2;
            b1 = GetDes(this.Binary);
            Console.WriteLine(b1);
            b2 = GetDes(str);
            Console.WriteLine(b2);
 
            return GetBin(4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так у вас уже есть отдельный класс, всё сделано, или я не понял ничего. Сформулируйте проблему конкретнее, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @aepot надо наверное свистоперделки всякие использовать, чтобы сложно выглядело

Comment: @Aarnihauta не, автор просто не может слововыразить, где у него проблема.

Comment: Код, который я написал, это от 6 лабораторной работы. А следующая лабораторка заключается в усложнении данного кода. Я сам если честно не понял, что от меня хотят, поэтому и обратился к вам!

Comment: @YarikHinkin раз Вы не поняли, что от вас хотят, то Вам будет сложно помочь. Покажите текст задания, может так что-то станет понятнее

Comment: @iKuzmichov 
Задание:
Задание будет заключаться в усложнении проекта из лабораторной работы №6. Теперь задание нужно реализовать в отдельном классе. Объекты класса создаются, и вызов методов осуществляется в основном классе в методе Main(). По возможности реализовать перегрузку математический операций.
Скопировал из методички.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot , да! Спасибо вам большое. Я просто скопировал, что вы написали и вставил себе. Надеюсь, что препод примет лабораторку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас каша в методах, какие-то шифры вместо названий, не жалейте букв, пишите нормальные слова в названиях методов.

Методы и классы в C# называть надо с большой буквы.

Вот, смотрите.

```
public class Binary
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public Binary(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string text, out Binary result)
    {
        try
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(text, 2);
            result = new Binary(number);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static Binary operator +(Binary left, Binary right)
    {
        return new Binary(left._value + right._value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Convert.ToString(_value, 2);
    }
}
```

Всё просто и понятно. Я выбросил численную реализацию преобразований из десятичной системы в двоичную и обратно, заменил встроенными в .NET методами. Такое решение препод конечно же не примет, но вы можете всё исправить. Я просто отвечаю на вопрос, что где должно быть.

Использовать это тоже не сложно.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Binary b1 = ReadBinary("Введите 1-е двоичное число: ");
        Binary b2 = ReadBinary("Введите 2-е двоичное число: ");
        Binary sum = b1 + b2;
        Console.WriteLine($"Сумма двоичных чисел: {sum}");
    }

    private static Binary ReadBinary(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Binary.TryParse(text, out Binary binary))
                return binary;
            Console.WriteLine("Не удалось распознать двоичное число, попробуйте еще раз");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите 1-е двоичное число: erfdf
Не удалось распознать двоичное число, попробуйте еще раз
Введите 1-е двоичное число: 21323
Не удалось распознать двоичное число, попробуйте еще раз
Введите 1-е двоичное число: 101
Введите 2-е двоичное число: 1ff
Не удалось распознать двоичное число, попробуйте еще раз
Введите 2-е двоичное число: 111
Сумма двоичных чисел: 1100
```